# Different font size for UILabel using adaptive layout

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, size-classes, adaptive-ui

In Xcode 6 we have a new feature called adaptive layout. By using that I have created a new project in which it I need to have different font size based on the layout.

In iPhone 3.5 inch screen I must have font size as 17pt, and other screen size in iPhone must be 21pt.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this using adaptive layout?

Comment: check this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started), you have to scroll down to Adaptive Fonts section, there is something similar to what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do with storyboad. There is a + sign on the left of the font, click it and select the size class and choose the font size needed

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But my doubt how to achieve different font size for different iPhone screen.

Answer (score 2):

In viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear, you can detect the size of the layout. You only have to update font size based on the detected size.
 
You can use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];` or in iOS8 : `[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds];`

Comment: In the latest xcode 6 we can set the font size for UILabel using attribute inspector in storyboard and I need to how should I achieve it using storyboard and also this one also helps me.