# How to set different Font sizes for different iPhone screen size using storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uistoryboard

I have a title in my screen whose font size is 16 but in iPhone 5s/4s it looks slightly bigger, so I want to adjust font size based on different iPhone screen size.
Is it possible via storyboard?

Comment: Via, storyboard, only iPhone and iPad, v can do it.. for this, Coding

Comment: @McDonal_11 can you provide me with some sample codes or links..that would be great.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630776/uitextview-font-to-always-be-fixed-size/48646121#48646121 get answer from here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236145/different-font-size-for-uilabel-using-adaptive-layout

Comment: You can vary the font size using `Traits` in `Storyboard`.

Comment: @sachin_kvk checkout my question

Comment: Check below link:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496831/5857254 Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can ask iOS to adapt automatically, BUT using Apple directions.
By the way apple states: (since ios7)

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/

1) "Use built-in text styles whenever possible." (algorithm is form apple..)

2) "Dynamic Type provides additional flexibility by letting readers choose their preferred text size."

So Apple has already took in account all variations on devices and fonts and user preferences. (maybe is NOT what you want.. but is the official way to scale / adapt fonts)

Answer (score 0):

By using xCode  you can give dynamic font like this way 
check bellow image

1. Click on "+" button near font setting in image you can see that
2. select size of scree and assign font type and size.

**Setup Font**

[image]

After setting up

[image]

Comment: i think this is for ipad and iphone.. i need solution for iphones only.